# Read from REST to Stream of Java Pojos

Tags: json, rest, java-8, java-stream

I'm struggling with Java8 streams.

Need to read  list of JSON objects from external REST service and unmarshall it to POJOs

What is the best approach for it?

Answer (score 1):

Use JAX-RS client like [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html) or [RESTEasy](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-3/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html) for that and don't bother using Java8 streams unless you there is a very specific reason for doing that (if you have one - please post it here).